# Least Squares estimators for VARX process

Tags: self-study, least-squares, vector-autoregression, estimators

The following is an assignment so please do not provide complete answers. I just need an hint since I spent hours coming up with nothing.

The problem is the following. Given a stationary VARX process

$$ Y(t) = \mu + \sum_{p=1}^P \mathbf{A}_pY(t-p) + \mathbf{B}U(t) + \epsilon(t) $$

with $Y(t) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $t=1,\dots ,T$ and $U(t)$ is a vector representing the external factors. I have to derive an analytical estimator for $\theta = (\mu, A_1,\dots,A_P,B)$ using Least Squares.

I therefore defined

$$ e(t) = Y(t) - \mu -  \sum_{p=1}^P \mathbf{A}_pY(t-p) - \mathbf{B}U(t)$$

and computed

$$ RSS = \sum_{t=1}^T e(t)^2. $$

The next step would be compute the partial derivatives but here come the problems. For instance, taking the partial derivative with respect to $\mu$ would lead to

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \mu} RSS = 2\sum_{t=1}^T \left(Y(t) - \mu -  \sum_{p=1}^P \mathbf{A}_pY(t-p) - \mathbf{B}U(t) \right).$$

Is the process correct?

Comment: What is $U(t)$? Is it observable?

Comment: @MatthewGunn I added a description. I have some problems with the dimensions of the vectors and the matrices: in the assignment are wrong, I guess.